# GCC 6.3.1 doesn't autovectorize without -ffinite-math-only

Tags: gcc, arm, neon, armv7, auto-vectorization

I would like to understand why GCC does not autovectorize the following loop, unless I pass the -ffinite-math-only. As to my understanding and the GCC manual the optimization requires the `-funsafe-math-optimizations`

> If the selected floating-point hardware includes the NEON extension (e.g. -mfpu=neon), note that floating-point operations are not generated by GCC's auto-vectorization pass unless -funsafe-math-optimizations is also specified.  This is because NEON
>              hardware does not fully implement the IEEE 754 standard for floating-point arithmetic (in particular denormal values are treated as zero), so the use of NEON instructions may lead to a loss of precision.

In particular, the flag enables the compiler to assume associative math, so that it can first accumulate with 4 partial sums. The code seems pretty straight forward

```
template<typename SumType = double>
class UipLineResult {
public:
   SumType sqsum;
   SumType dcsum;
   float pkp;
   float pkn;

public:
   UipLineResult() {
      clear();
   }

   void clear() {
      sqsum = 0;
      dcsum = 0;
      pkp = -std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
      pkn = +std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
   }
};
```

Loop that is not vectorized

```
static void addSamplesLine(const float* ss, UipLineResult<>* line) {
   UipLineResult<float> intermediate;
   for(int idx = 0; idx < 120; idx++) {
      float s = ss[idx];
      intermediate.sqsum += s * s;
      intermediate.dcsum += s;
      intermediate.pkp = intermediate.pkp < s ? s : intermediate.pkp;
      intermediate.pkn = intermediate.pkn > s ? s : intermediate.pkn;
   }
   line->addIntermediate(&intermediate);
}
```

For example, the squared addition look like

```
      intermediate.sqsum += s * s;
107da:       ee47 6aa7       vmla.f32        s13, s15, s15
```

With `-ffinite-math-only` this becomes

```
      intermediate.sqsum += s * s;
1054c:       ef40 6df0       vmla.f32        q11, q8, q8
```

Compiler flags

> -funsafe-math-optimizations -ffinite-math-only -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you got it to vectorize that loop at all. GCC doesn't know how to vectorize conditionals. I usually just write intrinsics in these cases instead of wasting time fighting limitations of the compiler.

Comment: @BitBank the min-max with the conditional is vectorized using `vmaxq` and `vminq`, here.

Comment: So basically you are asking why -funsafe-math-optimizations does not imply -ffinite-math-only?

Comment: gcc needs -ffinite-math-only to recognize that `(a<b)?a:b` is `min(a,b)`.

Comment: @marc not sure. I'm asking why -fno-finite-math-only breaks autovectorization here. Assuming that infinite or nans aren't present is much severe that just assuming that zero is unsigned or addition is associative, so I think I know the answer to "why -funsafe-math-optimizations does not imply -ffinite-math-only?". Given that NEON can handle NANs and infinity, it is a mystery to me why that flag is needed.

Comment: @marc ah, interesting. So it won't vectorize the other operations as well then? I imagine it could use scalar instructions for that and vector instructions for the others

Comment: Vectorization is usually all or nothing. If you start taking the vector apart and building it again, you quickly lose the benefits. In this case, it would be doable, either through unrolling or loop splitting, but that's getting a bit specialized.

Comment: @marc alternatively I think I could invert the conditions and swap both branches of the conditional? Then, NAN results would propagate throughout. Would that help with the vectorization?

Comment: NVM, that won't work. Thanks for the help. If you answer, I will accept.